# Read json with multiple values

Tags: c#, json, interface

I have this code snippet from my method. It should write all parts of the list test.E_id, but it writes nothing. I don't know what i do wrong.

```
string jsonText = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
Execution test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Execution>(jsonText);
    foreach (string eID in test.E_id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(eID);
    }
```

This is my Execution class, besides the writing of the strings is working fine.

```
public class Execution
{
    public string Usr_id { get; private set; }
    public string Patient_id { get; private set; }
    public List<string> E_id { get; private set; }
    public List<string> E_title { get; private set; }
    public List<string> E_description { get; private set; }
    public List<string> E_date { get; private set; }
    public List<string> E_delete { get; private set; }

    public Execution(string usr_id, string patient_id, List<string> e_id, List<string> e_title, List<string> e_description,
    List<string> e_date, List<string> e_delete)
    {
        Usr_id = usr_id;
        Patient_id = patient_id;
        E_id = e_id;
        E_title = e_title;
        E_description = e_description;
        E_date = e_date;
        E_delete = e_delete;
    }
}
```

And here is the json file i want to read from:

```
{
    "usr_id":"573",
    "patient_id":"170510024",
    "executions":[
        {
            "id":"SF70H",
            "title":"Verbandswechsel",
            "description":"Verband des rechten Armes wechseln",
            "date":"2017-07-28T12:00:00.000Z",
            "delete":false
        },
        {
            "id":"SF18H",
            "title":"Physiotherapie",
            "description":"Beweglichkeit des Knies wiederherstellen",
            "date":"2017-07-28T14:00:00.000Z",
            "delete":false
        }
    ]
```

Maybe anyone knows what i do wrong and can help me to find my mistake.
    }

Comment: I have strong feeling that c# class is not equivalent to json structure. Copy your json and in either view or edit menu in visual studio there is paste special menu click there which will create c# class for copied json structure. And also you should remove Execution constructor.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+paste+json+as+class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your JSON and the code don't match with each other. You have lists for single fields, you have wrong names, etc.

Use this C# which maps to your JSON (generated from [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)):

```
public class Execution
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public bool delete { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public string usr_id { get; set; }
    public string patient_id { get; set; }
    public List<Execution> executions { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this C# code:

```
Test test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(jsonText);
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend *not* using that C# directly though - instead giving things C#-idiomatic names, and using `[JsonProperty]` to specify the name to use/parse in JSON.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, but often for most novice users a bridge too far.

Comment: Good habit to get into though - I'm not suggesting changing the sample code, so much as just adding a suggestion at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code structure does not match your JSON-structure. Since you already knew the structure of the JSON file, there's a handy tool in Visual Studio to help you generate code from that.

*Select the JSON structure in the file -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> -> Visual Studio -> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as classes.*

This gives following result:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string usr_id { get; set; }
    public string patient_id { get; set; }
    public Execution[] executions { get; set; }
}

public class Execution
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public bool delete { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can decorate it with JsonProperty attributes and make the names to the C# standards:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty("usr_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("patient_id")]
    public string PatientId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("executions ")]
    public Execution[] Executions { get; set; }
}

public class Execution
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("datee")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("delete")]
    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine:

```
public class ExecutionOrder
{
    public string Usr_id { get; set; }
    public string Patient_id { get; set; }
    public List<Execution> Executions { get; set; }

    public ExecutionOrder(string usr_id, string patient_id, List<Execution> executions)
    {
        Usr_id = usr_id;
        Patient_id = patient_id;
        Executions = executions;
    }

}

public class Execution
{
    public string E_id { get; set; }
    public string E_title { get; set; }
    public string E_description { get; set; }
    public string E_date { get; set; }
    public bool E_delete { get; set; }

    public Execution(string e_id, string e_title, string e_description, string e_date, bool e_delete)
    {
        E_id = e_id;
        E_title = e_title;
        E_description = e_description;
        E_date = e_date;
        E_delete = e_delete;
    }

}
```

But now I have another problem, i want to read the strings and the bool from the Execution object and print it in the CommandWindow. I can print the Usr_id and the Patient_id without any problems, and the bool from the object is also shown. But it doesn't print the strings. Is it the right way to read the strings out of the object?

```
ExecutionOrder test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExecutionOrder>(jsonText);
test.Executions.ForEach(delegate(Execution exec)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test.Usr_id);
    Console.WriteLine(test.Patient_id);
    Console.WriteLine(exec.E_id);
    Console.WriteLine(exec.E_title);
    Console.WriteLine(exec.E_description);
    Console.WriteLine(exec.E_date);
    Console.WriteLine(exec.E_delete);
    Console.WriteLine();
});
```